# What is the proper way to free memory from a struct from a double pointer?

Tags: c, algorithm, structure

```
// deallocate all dynamically allocated memory associated 
//    with the Item indicated by the handle argument
//    and set the Item pointer to NULL

    void deleteItem(Item** item) {
        free(item->name);
        free(item);
        *item = NULL;
    }
```

itemDB struct holds **Item theItems.

item struct holds a *char name.

supplied error message.

"make
gcc -c item.c -g -Wall
item.c: In function ‘deleteItem’:
item.c:48:12: error: request for member ‘name’ in something not a structure or union
  free(&item->name);
            ^
Makefile:14: recipe for target 'item.o' failed
make: *** [item.o] Error 1"

Comment: I think you're missing a couple of stars there.

Comment: Specifically, `item->name` should be `(*item)->name`, etc.

Comment: You'll also need `free(*item)` instead of `free(item)`

Comment: How many `malloc`s you use in construction of `item`, how many `free`s you need to call here.

Comment: That is really not a usual pattern for a C program... specially the "and set the Item pointer to NULL".

Comment: @Stargateur. I've seen this pattern quite a bit. Not a huge fan myself, but it's definitely out there. It's sometimes implemented as a macro, e.g., Py_CLEAR in the a Python extension API

Comment: There is nothing wrong with setting the pointer `NULL` after a `free`, and that is the only reason a pointer-to-pointer need be passed, otherwise passing a simple-pointer would be sufficient.

Comment: Don't use `**`, problem solved. Or if you insist on setting the pointer to NULL, use `(*item)` all over.

Answer (score 3):

You add an extra star. `Item**` is a pointer to a pointer to an `Item` structure. `->` works with a pointer to a structure. `free` expects a pointer to the memory you want to free.

You need to dereference the pointer-to-a-pointer to get the pointer. Specifically, the first two lines in your function should read:

```
free((*item)->name);
free(*item);
```

The first line deallocates the memory pointed to by the `name` field of the structure, the second deallocates the structure itself.

The line `*item = NULL;` is probably correct by the way. It sets the *pointer* to NULL, so it can't be confused with the memory it pointed to, which is now deallocated.

Comment: I between, "yes this answer is correct" and "these lines shouldn't appear in C unless a very good reason and I should not upvote an answer that say to do it" :-p

Comment: Oh, I'm not saying to do it. But if you're going to do it, do it right. If there's a way to do something, I'm not a big fan of telling people not to. Kinda why I love C in the first place.

Comment: That funny because, I think the exact opposite, like in C you can do all you want, you need to be super careful, and avoid bad pattern like global, not check error, etc. Do a function that always set to NULL your pointer mean for me that you don't fully control your pointer. Then two choices, the code will not check for NULL anyway so this is useless, the code check for NULL but that use CPU time that "could" be avoid. For me, safe language like java or C#, allow to be more flexible about the code. I'm like linus who get angry at any bad code in C ;), but without insult people about it.

Comment: There are some good reasons to NULL your pointers, especially if you're processing an array, as OP seems to imply doing. Having a marker saying "this one has been processed", for example. This pattern is not bad enough to justify making sweeping generalizations about it.